# Remember accordion state on go back page

Tags: html, jquery, accordion

I have multiple accordions on an archive page with a default state as collapsed.
Each accordion has links and when I click on one of them I land on their own page and, of course, when I go back the accordions are all collapsed.
What I do want to do, instead, is to go back on the archive page and find the accordions clicked as opened.

This is an example of accordion in HTML:

```
<div class="zn_accordion--shortcode acc--style2 panel-group ">
 <div class="acc-group ">
 <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#acc5fd8b3656f7b0" class="acc-tgg-button text-custom collapsed btn-link">Title
 </button>
  <div id="acc5fd8b3656f7b0" class="acc-panel-collapse collapse ">
   <div class="acc-content">
    <div class="sub-child-wrap p10-10 d-4 t-4 ts-6 m-all">
     <a href=“link” class="sub-child block"<h5>Title</h5></a>
    </div>
   <div class="clear"></div>
   </div><!-- /.acc-content -->
  </div>
 </div><!-- end /.acc-group -->
</div>
<div class="zn_accordion--shortcode acc--style2 panel-group ">
 <div class="acc-group ">
 <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#acc5fd8b3656f7b0" class="acc-tgg-button text-custom collapsed btn-link">Title
 </button>
  <div id="acc5fd8b3656f7b0" class="acc-panel-collapse collapse ">
   <div class="acc-content">
    <div class="sub-child-wrap p10-10 d-4 t-4 ts-6 m-all">
     <a href=“link” class="sub-child block"<h5>Title</h5></a>
    </div>
   <div class="clear"></div>
   </div><!-- /.acc-content -->
  </div>
 </div><!-- end /.acc-group -->
</div>
<div class="zn_accordion--shortcode acc--style2 panel-group ">
 <div class="acc-group ">
 <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#acc5fd8b3656f7b0" class="acc-tgg-button text-custom collapsed btn-link">Title
 </button>
  <div id="acc5fd8b3656f7b0" class="acc-panel-collapse collapse ">
   <div class="acc-content">
    <div class="sub-child-wrap p10-10 d-4 t-4 ts-6 m-all">
     <a href=“link” class="sub-child block"<h5>Title</h5></a>
    </div>
   <div class="clear"></div>
   </div><!-- /.acc-content -->
  </div>
 </div><!-- end /.acc-group -->
</div>
<div class="zn_accordion--shortcode acc--style2 panel-group ">
<div class="acc-group ">
<button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#acc5fd8b3656f7b0" class="acc-tgg-button text-custom collapsed btn-link">Title
</button>
<div id="acc5fd8b3656f7b0" class="acc-panel-collapse collapse ">
<div class="acc-content">
<div class="sub-child-wrap p10-10 d-4 t-4 ts-6 m-all">
<a href=“link” class="sub-child block"<h5>Title</h5></a></div><div class="clear"></div></div><!-- /.acc-content --></div> </div><!-- end /.acc-group --> </div>
<div class="zn_accordion--shortcode acc--style2 panel-group ">
 <div class="acc-group ">
  <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#acc5fd8882426e1e"
  class="acc-tgg-button text-custom btn-link" aria-expanded="true">Title
  </button>
  <div id="acc5fd8882426e1e" class="acc-panel-collapse collapse in" aria-expanded="true">
   <div class="acc-content">
     <div class="sub-child-wrap p10-10 d-4 t-4 ts-6 m-all">
      <a href="link" class="sub-child block"">
       <h5>Title</h5>
      </a>
     </div>
     <div class="clear"></div>
   </div><!-- /.acc-content -->
  </div>
 </div><!-- end /.acc-group -->
</div>
```

And my Jquery code:

```
 $(".acc-tgg-button").click(function () {

 $(".acc-tgg-button[aria-expanded='true']").not(this).click();
```

I tried to use [docCookies.js](https://github.com/bibliolabs/docCookies) but I can't figure out how to use it to make it remember the last state of the accordions like this. I tried this code but I'm really stuck here:

```
$(".acc-tgg-button").click(function () {
  $(".acc-tgg-button[aria-expanded='true']").not(this).click();
  docCookies.setItem('acc-tgg-button', 'true', '', '','', true);
});
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: please add two or more accordions.

Comment: I've added some more accordions with a 'collapse' class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it in a new mind-blowing way

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(window).unload(function() {
        var accTggButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".acc-tgg-button"); 
            accTggButtons.forEach((element, i) => {  
                if (element.getAttribute('aria-expanded') === "true") {
                    window.sessionStorage.setItem(window.location.pathname, i); 
                }
            });
    });
    $(window).on('load', function (event) { 
        var id = JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem(window.location.pathname));
        if(id){
            $('.acc-tgg-button').eq(id).click();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML - changes

```
<a href="link" class="sub-child block" onclick="setCookie('acc5fd8b3656f7b01')">
  <h5>Title</h5>
</a>
```

I have added an anchor tag on onclick function call.

Jquery Changes
add below function into your script tag.

```
  function getCookie(name) {
    var value = "; " + document.cookie;
    var parts = value.split("; " + name + "=");
    if (parts.length == 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
  }

  function check_last_accordion() {
    latest_accordion = getCookie('latest_accordion')
    if (latest_accordion != undefined || latest_accordion != '') {
      $("button.acc-tgg-button[data-target='#" + latest_accordion + "']").click()
    }
  }

  function setCookie(accordion_id) {
    document.cookie = "latest_accordion=" + accordion_id + "; path=/"
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    check_last_accordion()
  })
```

Run it and let me know if is there any issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not work. When I click on a link, I read this inside the console

'Uncaught ReferenceError: setCookie is not defined'

Comment: i think you forgot to add added misplaced javascript function getCookie, check_last_accordion, and setCookie

add those functions in the script tag at bottom of your HTML.

Comment: I'm sorry but even if now the console is clear, it still doesn't work as expected

Comment: $term_subchild = get_term($term_subchild, 'project_category');
 $acc_content .= '<div class="sub-child-wrap p10-10 d-4 t-4 ts-6 m-all">';
$acc_content .= '<a href="' . get_permalink(get_the_ID()) . '" class="sub-child block" onclick="setCookie(\'acc5fd8b3656f7b01\')">';
$acc_content .= '<h5> ' . get_the_title(get_the_ID()) . '</h5>';
$acc_content .= '</a>';
 $acc_content .= '</div>';

Comment: <script>
    function getCookie(name) {
        var value = "; " + document.cookie;
        var parts = value.split("; " + name + "=");
        if (parts.length === 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
    }

    function check_last_accordion() {
        var latest_accordion = getCookie('latest_accordion');
        if (latest_accordion !== undefined || latest_accordion !== '') {
            $("button.acc-tgg-button[data-target='#" + latest_accordion + "']").click()
        }
    }

Comment: function setCookie(accordion_id) {
        document.cookie = "latest_accordion=" + accordion_id + "; path=/"
    }
</script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        check_last_accordion()
    })

Comment: without error how can guess error? if you can provide me anything then I can try my best to solve your problem.

Comment: The only warning I see is
“latest_accordion” will be soon rejected because it has the “sameSite” attribute set to “none” or an invalid value, without the “secure” attribute. To know more about the “sameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite'